# How to use more than one date picker on a page

Tags: javascript, forms, datepicker

I am trying to add two date pickers to my form, but can not get even one picker to display correctly. Here is the code I found. Thanks for any help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.datetime').datetimepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        timeFormat: 'h:m'
    });
</script>
```

Here is my HTML

```
<tr>
  <td><input type="text" name="expiration_date" class="" id="datepicker[0]" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="action_date" class="" id="datepicker[1]" /></td>
</tr>
```

Im am new to javascript so thank you for your help.

Comment: To add to what the other posters have said, I would recommend you use id rather than name.  So, your ids should be expiration_date and action_date rather than datepicker[0] and datepicker[1].  It will make your code much easier to read and follow.

Comment: @Maess `name` I get the impression this is being used for data-binding so there might be a particular reason why the `name` / `id` attributes are set in this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because your selector i.e. `$('.datetime')` is looking for all elements with a `datetime` class set (of which you have none). All your input's all have `class=""`, for this to work you need to change these to `class="datetime"` i.e.

```
<input type="text" name="expiration_date" class="datetime" id="datepicker[0]" />
<input type="text" name="action_date" class="datetime" id="datepicker[1]" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing to add *`class name`*

```
<input type="text" name="expiration_date" class="" id="datepicker[0]" />
```

Add it

```
<input type="text" name="expiration_date" class="datetime" id="datepicker[0]" />
<input type="text" name="expiration_date" class="datetime" id="datepicker[1]" />
```

or you can even you can do this **`id`**

```
$("input[id^='datepicker']").datetimepicker({ //looks for id starting with datepicker
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        timeFormat: 'h:m'
    });
```